# How do i access the textField in my alertView? Trying to see if password matches current user. parse/swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, uialertview, logout

I am trying to make an alert appear when the user tries to click on the logOut button. Then the user will be asked to re-type their password in order to logout.

Here is my code.

```
     @IBAction func logOut(sender: AnyObject) {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Are You Sure You Want To Log Out?", message: "Please Enter Your Password", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { (textField) -> Void in
        }

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Log Out", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
        let textF = alert.textFields![0] as UITextField

        if textF.text! != PFUser.currentUser()?.password {
            print("Cannot Log Out")

        } else if textF.text! == PFUser.currentUser()?.password! {
            PFUser.logOut()
            let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()
            print(currentUser)
        }
    }))

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
        if action == true {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
        }}))

self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

When i click cancel on the alertView it closes the alert and the user is not logged out. **Perfect!**

If i type in random letters my debugger console prints "Cannot logout"(which i will change later for another alertview saying incorrect password) **Perfect!**

**The Issue is**
Even if i type the correct password it is saying "cannot logout" which to me means that i am not accessing:

```
    PFUser.CurrentUser.password
```

Any views on fixing this? - Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you do a little debugging? Start by printing both `textF.text` and `PFUser.currentUser().password` and see what the two value actually are. Then you see why they are different even when you think they are the same.

Comment: Matthew, you can't access the password like that, Parse has that on lockdown. You have to do like RMaddy said above, this may work to write the field value out, but then you have to probably store this in a string value first and then compare the string to what you want. Parse requires that you use explictly defined functions to deal with passwords like "logInWith ... " and PFUser Logout or whatever the method is called.

Comment: Should you wish to do comparisons on passwords, explicitly, like you are trying to do, then I'd suggest either bcrypting the password yoursefl in another field in your _User table on parse or storing the username/password yourself manually, outside of what Parse does, in IOS keychain service on the user's device. This will make these two values persistent through app deletes, but NOT persistent, most likely, with iphone resets.

Comment: @rmaddy when i print `textF.text` i get what i typed in there. when i try printing `PFUser.currentUser().password` i get nil

Comment: Also, Mr. Ehrlich, you should follow Parse's advice on this one, if you want to check the password for verification again when they try to log out, you should just run this again: [PFUser logInWithUsernameInBackground:email password:password block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {}]; .. this is from my memory of their advice for using the IOS SDK, if you want to check the password, EVER AGAIN in the app, just run the login function again and see what it returns. I can't verify that it will retrun success or failure if the user is already logged in, but I can verify ...

Comment: ... continued from above ... that this is the sort of method that Parse.com would rather have you employ than checking the password field yourself since Passwords aren't stored on Parse's tableview database set that you can see on your end in yoru parse account.

Comment: @Larcerax so you are saying i should run the login method where? in `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: I'd say, just run the login method again right there where you have the if textF.text! != PFUser.currentUser()?.password {
            print("Cannot Log Out") ... I say this because this is techincally what you are after, from what I gather,  .. you just want to reverify a password, and this should do it, so use the "success" method inside the login block to check if the password returned as true "matches" or !success to check if the password the user entered is wrong.

Comment: @Larcerax Oh! it lets me check for username! so maybe i should just have the user input his username instead of password to log out. Building a SaaS app, so really the only person who should have the username is the manager of said business anyway.

Comment: Yeah, you can do it that way, but you will have access to their email address and username .. parse doesn't lock this one down, you can retrieve this from the PFUser object. So, really your same method works, you just manually use their Username/Email address that you extract from the PFUser object (since the user is presumably already logged in) and then ask for their password. No need to bother the user with the Username again since you can access it yourself, but you can't access the password in the PFUser object, you can only call to reverify credentials with Parse.

Comment: @Larcerax it worked with username! i was able to logout

Comment: @Larcerax just using Username and Password upon logging in.

Comment: @Larcerax once they activate the product(pay $) i give them a Username / password to log in with.